# Sum elements in a channel in caffe

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

If I have a 4-D blob, say of size (40,1024,300,1) and I want to average pool across the second channel and generate an output of size (40,1,300,1), how would I do it? I think the reduction layer collapses the whole blob and generates a blob of size (40) by summing elements in all other axises (after 1) also. Is there any work around for this without re-implementing a new layer?

Answer (score 2):

The only easy workaround I found is as follows. Permute your blob to a shape `(40,300,1,1024)`. Use reduction layer to compute the mean with `axis = -1` and `operation = MEAN`. I think the blob will be of shape `(40,300,1)`. You may need to use `reshape` to append an extra dimension at the end (check if this is needed) and then permute back to shape `(40,1,300,1)`.

You can find an implementation of a `Permute` layer [here](https://github.com/intel/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/permute_layer.cpp) or [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/b68695db42aa79e874296071927536363fe1efbf/src/caffe/layers/permute_layer.cpp). I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought of using wei's branch. Its pretty weird that a simple operation like this is not supported in caffe. I ended up implementing the cuda kernels as they were not very complicated for this particular case.

Comment: Did you implement the CUDA kernels for Wei's branch or a totally new layer? Let me know if you plan to share this part of your code anytime.

Comment: It's a new layer, only works for pooling on channel dimension. Once I test it properly, i'll share it on github.